# react-bootstrap on Google Chrome : the horizontal scrollbar of my div shifts a little to the left when it is on the far right when I close my modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

Has someone already had this problem? Do I have to change the library for the modals?
I just want my horizontal scrollbar in my div to stay on the right when I close my modal. However, the scrollbar shifts a little to the left. This problem only happens on Google Chrome

```
              <div style={{ overflowY: 'auto', overflowX: 'hidden', padding: '14px' }}>
                {residents.map((x, i) => {
                  return (

                    <div key={i}>
                      <div key={i} className="box">
                        <Row>
                          <div className="add-residents-delete-inputs">
                            {residents.length !== 1 &&
                              <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>x</Button>}
                          </div>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '30px'
                            }}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="validationCustom01">
                              <InputGroup style={{ width: 'fit-content' }} hasValidation>

                                <Form.Control
                                  required
                                  className="ml10"
                                  name="lastname"
                                  placeholder="Nom *"
                                  value={x.lastname}
                                  onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} />

                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                  <small> {error} </small>
                                </Form.Control.Feedback>

                              </InputGroup>
                            </Form.Group>
                          </Col>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '46px'
                            }}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="validationCustom02">
                              <InputGroup style={{ width: 'fit-content' }} hasValidation>

                                <Form.Control
                                  required
                                  name="firstname"
                                  placeholder="Prénom *"
                                  value={x.firstname}
                                  onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} />

                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                  <small> {error} </small>
                                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                              </InputGroup>
                            </Form.Group>
                          </Col>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '45px'
                            }}>
                            <FormGroup controlId="validationCustom03">

                              <Form.Select
                                required
                                name="gender"
                                placeholder="Genre"
                                value={x.gender}
                                style={{ backgroundColor: "#5CB2C4", color: "white" }}
                                onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}>
                                <option value="M">Homme</option>
                                <option value="F">Femme</option>
                              </Form.Select>

                            </FormGroup>
                          </Col>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '46px'
                            }}>
                            <FormGroup controlId="validationCustom04">
                              <Form.Select

                                name="texture"
                                placeholder="Texture"
                                defaultValue={x.texture}
                                onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}>
                                <option value="">Entier</option>
                                <option value="chopped">Haché</option>
                                <option value="mixed">Mixé</option>
                              </Form.Select>

                            </FormGroup>
                          </Col>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '42px'
                            }}>
                            <FormGroup controlId="validationCustom05">

                              <Form.Control
                                required
                                name="diet"
                                placeholder="Protocole Alimentaire"
                                style={{ backgroundColor: "white", color: "black" }}
                                // We can also use defaultValue ={residentInputValue[i].profil} for example.
                                defaultValue={x.diet}
                                onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} />

                            </FormGroup>
                          </Col>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '46px'
                            }}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="validationCustom02">
                              <InputGroup style={{ width: 'fit-content' }} hasValidation>

                                <Form.Control
                                  style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'black' }}
                                  name="residence_location"
                                  placeholder="Service"
                                  value={x.residence_location}
                                  onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)} />

                              </InputGroup>
                            </Form.Group>
                          </Col>
                          <Col
                            style={{
                              marginLeft: '102px'
                            }}>
                            <FormGroup controlId="validationCustom06">

                              <Button value={x.aversions.map(aversions => aversions.name)} id={i} variant="success"
                                onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                                onClick={e => handleOpen(e, i)}>+</Button>
                              <p>
                                {residents[i].aversions.map((aversion, index) => {
                                  return (
                                    <span key={index}>
                                      {index === residents[i].aversions.length - 1
                                        ? aversion.name + ' (' + aversion.type + ')' : aversion.name +
                                        ' (' + aversion.type + ')' + ', '}
                                    </span>
                                  );
                                })
                                }
                              </p>

                            </FormGroup>
                          </Col>

                        </Row>
                      </div>
                      <ReusableModal sectionRef={sectionRef} btnRef={btnRef} show={showModal} onClose={onClose}
                        name="aversions"
                        handleSave={e => handleSave(e, i)} title="Ajout/suppression d'aversions">
                        <AddAversions sectionRef={sectionRef} aversions={aversions} isCheckedList={isCheckedList}
                          aversionsList={aversionsList}
                          onAversionsChange={onAversionsChange} onTypeChange={onTypeChange} residents={residents} />
                      </ReusableModal>
                    </div>
```

ReusableModal :

```
  return (
    <Modal keyboard centered backdrop={false} show={props.show} onHide={handleClose} style={{position: 'fixed'}}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>{props.title}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{props.children}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          Annuler
        </Button>
        <Button ref={btnRef} variant="primary" onClick={props.handleSave}>
          Sauvegarder
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
```

what I expect is to keep the position of the horizontal scrollbar of my center div all the way to the right when I close the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just had to move my Modal component under my .map(). Not inside.